# This Unity script makes a gameObject rotate around an object. How?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The code below is from [Unity's tutorial on Quaternions](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hd1QzLf4ZH8&list=PLX2vGYjWbI0S8YpPPKKvXZayCjkKj4bUP&index=15). If you copy/paste the code it makes your object orbit around the target. My question is: **WHY?** Why does it results on that? And why would I do it like that when I can just use transform.RotateAround()? Note that if you change the code SLIGHTLY it behaves completely differently. For instance, if I change the 3 to a -3, the object just runs away.

```
    public Transform target;

    void Update()
    {
        Vector3 relativePos = target.position - transform.position;
        Quaternion rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(relativePos);

        Quaternion current = transform.localRotation;

        transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Slerp(current, rotation, Time.deltaTime);
        transform.Translate(0, 0, 3 * Time.deltaTime);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First the givens.

`relativePos` is the vector direction from to target.
`LookRotation` is a function that derives a `Quaternion` from a vector you'd like your object to face towards.
`Slerp` Spherically interpolates rotation between two rotations meaning it rotates from a given rotation to another smoothly.

Now to the explanation.

It revolves around the target because of the `transform.Translate` without it your object will just rotate to face the target (because of the `LookRotation`) on its own axis with no movement. In the `tranform.Translate` the third parameter (3 * Time.deltaTime) means move the object forward along its z axis 3 units/second therefore it revoles because it's constantly trying to move 3 units/second on the z axis but the `Slerp` keeps pulling it in making it rotate towards the target so `tranform.Translate` moves it and `Slerp` keeps rotating it back to target which results in orbiting.

And you can't just use `transform.RotateAround()` because

1. You won't be able to configure which way your object faces it'll just revolve around a target. You can use it in combination with `transform.LookAt()` but that'll result in some jittery effects while on the code above `Slerp` Spherically interpolates rotation which basically means smoother rotation and less jittery.
2. You won't be able to specify rotation radius with `transform.Translate`

The object runs away because in `tranform.Translate` the third parameter (3 * Time.deltaTime) means move the object forward along its z axis 3 units/second while -3 means move it backward therefore it runs away But if you look closer it's still facing the target. Instead of moving back on the Z axis it moves back along the direction facing the target because of the `LookRotation` and `Slerp` functions.

I hope this explained it well if you have any more questions/need more clafication just reply and I'll get back to you.